# When does rails set the session id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sessionid

In our code we reset session info when the user logs in, so that a new session id is generated.  The session info is reset in the application controller during the process of logging in.  That reset clears the session id that came in with the login request.

I am unable to determine when a new session id is then generated.  Any ideas?  THANKS

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, but I think you should read this carefully: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

Answer (score 0):

> Sessions are lazily loaded. If you don’t access sessions in your
>   action’s code, they will not be loaded. Hence you will never need to
>   disable sessions, just not accessing them will do the job.

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

Meaning as soon as you access the `session` hash in your code it will be generated.